# Google Places autocomplete not working (in Bootstrap modal)

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, google-places-api

I'm trying to include a google places autocomplete input box in my React app.

I've followed the [guide here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete?authuser=1#places_searchbox) to place an `<input>` text field, and initializing the search box like so:

```
export default class MySearch extends class Component {
    ...

    componentDidMount() {
        var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
            new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');

        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, {
            bounds: defaultBounds
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            ...

            <input id="searchTextField"
                   type="text"
                   className="form-control"
                   placeholder="Search for a location"
            />
        );
    }
}
```

But I don't see any suggestions dropping down from the text field.

I inspected the networks tab, to see whether API requests are being hit as I type, and I, not only see requests, but responses from the API, with matching locations, based on my search term, as I type through.

I have no idea why the received suggestions are not being displayed in a dropdown suggestions list below my input box.

Thanks in advance :)

### Update

**PS**: I've placed the text box inside a bootstrap modal. When I place exactly the same text box, outside the bootstrap modal, it works like a breeze.

Any idea why the text box isn't showing suggestions while inside the modal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a styling issue, as the modal's z-index > dropdown's (`.pac-container`'s) z-index. Fixed it with the following CSS snippet:

```
.pac-container {
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 2001;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.modal{
    z-index: 2000;
}
.modal-backdrop{
    z-index: 1000;
}​
```

Comment: Hi, where exactly does this snippet go? and how does this .css file get referenced in the JSX? thanks

Answer (score 0):

## DOM reference (findDOMNode)

You should not select a dom element with id in react component. Use ref (reference) instead. Learn more about `findDOMNode` here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode

```
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';

export default class MySearch extends class Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
            new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

        var input = findDOMNode(this.refs['searchTextField']);

        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, {
            bounds: defaultBounds
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <input ref="searchTextField"
                   type="text"
                   className="form-control"
                   placeholder="Search for a location"
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck :\. You see I've logged the `document.getElementById('searchTextField')`, and I get this: `<input type="text" id="searchTextField" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a location" autocomplete="off">`